# It found my wifi during installation but it is missing after rebooting

Tags: wifi

I installed the os (Loki 0.4.1) on my Dell XPS M1530. At the beginning of the install it found my wireless network. I checked the boxes to install 3rd party drivers, and to download updates. The installation seemed to work perfectly.

When I reboot the network icon at the top of the screen has an x on it. Opening up network settings displays:
Ethernet Cable unplugged
VPN Disconnected
Proxy Disabled

How can I get my wireless to work, it worked during setup.

Thank you for your help.

Donald Lareau

ifconfig & ip link:

ifconfig
enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:9b:eb:20:56
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:23920 (23.9 KB)  TX bytes:23920 (23.9 KB)

ip link
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp9s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:9b:eb:20:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: It runs fine booting from the thumb drive. Can I install apps to my thumb drive and just use it this way?